# I can't get output from my code in Python

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist, runtime-error, physics

I'm trying to write a very simple code using the equation of state for Neutron stars. In the first stage, I define my constants and assign them to the list as the 1st element. Then I do my first-step equations and append them to the list as the second. I create a while loop for the next operations and append my lists within this loop. And at each step I print these appended constants to a out file.

```
"""
Created on Wed Oct 12 20:44:10 2022
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

f = open("radial.out","w")
### Constants
h_bar = 1.055e-27      # reduced planck constant (kg m2 s-1)
c = 2.99e+10           # m/s
G = 6.67430e-8        # Gravitational constant m^3/(kg*s)b
pi = 3.1415926535897
gamma =5/3
m_sun = 2.998e33
K = 1e10
rho_c = 2e15           # Density centeral kg/me3
P_c = K*rho_c**gamma
km = 1e5
dr = 10e3
M0 = (4*pi*(dr**3)*rho_c)/3

####Initial values for r = 0
N = 1600
m = np.zeros(N)
P = np.zeros(N)
rho = np.zeros(N)
r = np.zeros(N)
GR = np.zeros(N)

r[0] = 0
m[0] = 0
P[0] = P_c
rho[0] = rho_c
GR[0] = 0

data=r,rho,P,m,GR
f.write(str(data)+'\n')
np.savetxt("radial.out", m, delimiter=" ")

####### Second Appends
r[1] = dr
rho[1] = rho_c
P[1] = P_c
m[1] = 4*pi*r[1]**3*rho[1]/3 
GR[1] = 0

data=r,rho,P,m,GR
f.write(str(data)+'\n')
np.savetxt("radial.out", m,delimiter=" ")

for i in range(1,len(P)):
    while P[i] > 0:
        m[i+1] = m[i] + 4*pi*r[i]**2*rho[i]*dr
        rho[i+1] = (P[i]/K)**(3/5)
        GR[i+1] = (1 + (4*pi*r[i]**3*P[i])/(m[i]*c**2))*(1 + P[i]/(rho[i]*c**2))/(1 - (2*G*m[i])/(r[i]*c**2))
        P[i+1] = P[i] - (G * m[i] * rho[i] * GR[i])/ r[i]**2
        r[i+1] = r[i] + dr
        data=r,rho,P,m,GR
        f.write(str(data)+'\n')
        np.savetxt("radial.out", m,delimiter=" ")

f.close()
```

As a result it gives me an empty file, how can I proceed next.

Comment: You do `f.write()` and `np.savetxt()` on the same file . I would think that either a) one overwrites the other of b) one fails because the file has not been closed yet. More likely b).

Comment: Turns out the answer was 'a'

Answer (score 2):

The original program does two differnt write operators (file handle `f`, and np.savetxt) on the same file, and they both use **"w"** mode, which would overwrite the existing file. Changes both mode to "a" would solve the issue.

Recommendation:
Using only one method to write to a file is recommended(i.e. only use file handler `f` with `a` mode.  or visevers, only using np.savetxt for all writes operation..)

Be aware, to enable `np.savetxt` to append content, we need to provide its first argument `fname` to be a file handler with `a` mode.
i.e.

```
f=open('file.txt','a')
```

Then np.savetxt would append write content. i.e.

```
np.savetxt(f, m, delimiter=" ")
```

Comment: "only using np.savetxt" will probably overwrite the file each time

Comment: Thank you! 
This suggestion solved my problem now i can get my file output.

Answer (score -1):

I edited my code like this based on the answers I received and it solved my problem.

It appeared because I overprinted it using two different methods.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

f = open("radial.txt","a")
### Constants
h_bar = 1.055e-27      # reduced planck constant (kg m2 s-1)
c = 2.99e+10           # m/s
G = 6.67430e-8        # Gravitational constant m^3/(kg*s)b
pi = 3.1415926535897
gamma =5/3
m_sun = 2.998e33
K = 1e10
rho_c = 2e15           # Density centeral kg/me3
P_c = K*rho_c**gamma
km = 1e5
dr = 10e3
M0 = (4*pi*(dr**3)*rho_c)/3

####Initial values for r = 0
N = 1502
m = np.zeros(N)
P = np.zeros(N)
rho = np.zeros(N)
r = np.zeros(N)
GR = np.zeros(N)

r[0] = 0
m[0] = 0
P[0] = P_c
rho[0] = rho_c
GR[0] = 0

data=r,rho,P,m,GR
f.write(str(data)+'\n')
np.savetxt(f, (m,P,rho,r), delimiter=" ")

####### Second Appends
r[1] = dr
rho[1] = rho_c
P[1] = P_c
m[1] = 4*pi*r[1]**3*rho[1]/3 
GR[1] = 0

data=r,rho,P,m,GR
f.write(str(data)+'\n')
np.savetxt(f, (m,P,rho,r), delimiter=" ")

for i in range(1,len(P)):
    while P[i] > 0:
        m[i+1] = m[i] + 4*pi*r[i]**2*rho[i]*dr
        rho[i+1] = (P[i]/K)**(3/5)
        GR[i+1] = (1 + (4*pi*r[i]**3*P[i])/(m[i]*c**2))*(1 + P[i]/(rho[i]*c**2))/(1 - (2*G*m[i])/(r[i]*c**2))
        P[i+1] = P[i] - (G * m[i] * rho[i] * GR[i])/ r[i]**2
        r[i+1] = r[i] + dr
        data=r,rho,P,m,GR
        f.write(str(data)+'\n')
        np.savetxt(f, (m,P,rho,r), delimiter=" ")

f.close()
```